# Apache Virtual Host redirect to other server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

This is the situation:

Server A hosts "http://internal.intranet"

Server B hosts the internal application on "http://servernameb.intranet/foo/bar"

Server A needs to redirect all incoming http trafic to the adress of server B without users noticing it.

I can easly do this with the following config file:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.4.26>
  ServerName internal.intranet
  ServerAlias internal

  RewriteEngine on

  # Deny TRACE/TRACK request methods
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
  RewriteRule .* - [F]

  #RewriteRule "^/files(.*)$" "/files$1" [L]

  # Everything else not matched above needs to go to the servlet container
  # via HTTP listening on port 8008. The [P] flag (which is required)
  # implies that our requests will be handled by mod_proxy.
  RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "http://servernameb.intranet:8080/foo/bar/$1" [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

But then the problem is that the url shown in the users browser is: http://servernameb.intranet..... instead of http://internal.intranet

I don't want the users to get in contact with the servernameb address.

I know I probably need to use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse but i just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

you should try the following:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.4.26>
  ServerName internal.intranet
  ServerAlias internal

  ProxyPass        /  http://servernameb.intranet/foo/bar/
  ProxyPassReverse /  http://servernameb.intranet/foo/bar/
</VirtualHost>
```